# NoSuchMethodError using Guava 15 on Hadoop (2.3.0)

Tags: hadoop, guava, cloudera-cdh

I have a compiled jar for Hadoop including this library:

```
com.google.guava:guava:jar:15.0:compile
```

When I submit it into my Hadoop CDH5.0.1 cluster I have this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createStarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
    at com.trovit.pipeline.AdsPipelineDriver.main(AdsPipelineDriver.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

The main thing is that Hadoop has an older version of guava into its classpath, loads it before mine and crashes because the used function doesn't exist.

I've tried configuration parameters such as *mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence*, *mapreduce.task.classpath.first* or *mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first* but none of them worked.

Any guess for solving this problem?

Comment: Note that this was answered here: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/d5_HqUSvVl4